# How to subscribe to Kafka topic by key

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm super new to using Kafka, especially within a Kotlin service. I currently have a local broker which I'm able to send events to I'm trying to figure out how to subscribe to my topic and receive the message but I'm not able to actually consume the event by a key.

```
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@Service
class KafkaMessageConsumer {
    @Bean("consumerConfig")
    fun consumerConfigs(
        @Value("\${KAFKA_SASL_USERNAME}")
        kafkaServer: String,
        @Value("\${KAFKA_SASL_USERNAME}")
        userName: String,
        @Value("\${KAFKA_SASL_PASSWORD}")
        password: String,
        @Value("\${KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL}")
        schemaRegistryUrl: String,
        @Value("\${KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_USER_INFO}")
        schemaRegistryUserInfo: String
    ): Map<String, Any> {
        val config: MutableMap<String, Any> = mutableMapOf()
        config[ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = kafkaServer
        config[ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringDeserializer::class.java
        config[ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = KafkaAvroDeserializer::class.java
        config[KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.VALUE_SUBJECT_NAME_STRATEGY] = TopicRecordNameStrategy::class.java
        config[KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG] = schemaRegistryUrl

        return config
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = ["my.kafka.topic"], groupId = "group-id")
    fun consume(
        @Qualifier("consumerConfig")
        config: Map<String, Any>,
        message: String
    ) : Unit {
        val consumer: KafkaConsumer<String, String> = KafkaConsumer(config)

        println("message received from topic: $message")
    }
}
```

This is pretty much all I have. There are a list of IDs I have in the db that I would like to use to consume these events via a key that matches the ID. I'm using [this](https://dzone.com/articles/producer-consumer-with-kafka-and-kotlin) article as a reference

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to subscribe to a key.

You can change the function parameters to get a key in addition to the message record value (see docs on `@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_KEY)`), then you will just use normal if-statement to compare and look for specific keys for all partitions in the topic.

Related - [Message Filtering](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#filtering-messages)

Comment: thanks for responding. That's unfortunate, idk why I was under the impression that I'd be able to consume messages via a key. I did update my post to include some additional code that I've added but I'm seeing this error when I publish a new message: `Backoff none exhausted for ConsumerRecord(...` and `Endpoint handler details:
Method [public void com.my.package.kafka.consumer.KafkaMessageConsumer.consume(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ?>,java.lang.String)]`. I'm also fairly new to Kotlin so I'm having trouble figuring out where my type mismatch is.

Comment: You cannot pass your config map into the consume method. The KafkaListener annotation only allows specific parameter types, and a map generally isn't one unless that's the value of the Kafka record deserialization results. Plus, the consumer factory would already be configured at that point. You don't need to make a Consumer within the KafkaListener; Spring handles that for you. Please refer the documentation again on how to create a ConsumerFactory